How can I create a hollow window (with only the frame visible & interactable resize handles) using win32?
Would like to recreate this window (the topbar doesn't necessarily need to look the same, its the window resize handles I'm after):
https://i.sstatic.net/YjNsYXnx.png / https://imgur.com/a/haXzC1S / https://youtu.be/-mtmdFOAEJE
If anyone have the time, I would appreciate a short code snippet in any popular programming language - ideally using the win32 API.
